# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to return two tables in two querysets, using objects attributes filter and get. I tested on print function these two querysets and they are returning right. But the error continues. I believe that mistakes happen only in views.py.

```
def cliente_detail_view(request, slug):
    template_name = 'reconhecimento_facial/cliente_detail.html'
    obj = Cliente.objects.filter(Q(slug__icontains=slug) | Q(slug__iexact=slug))
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(slug__icontains=slug).id_cliente
    print(cliente)
    queryset2 = Exame.objects.filter(cliente_fk=cliente)
    
    print('cliente_detail_view')
    print(obj)
    context = {
        "object": obj,
        "object2": queryset2
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)


class ClienteDetailView(DetailView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        print('--------')
        print(slug)
        print('--------')
        if slug:
            queryset = Cliente.objects.filter(slug__icontains=slug)
            cliente = Cliente.objects.get(slug__icontains=slug).id_cliente
            print(cliente)
            queryset2 = Exame.objects.filter(cliente_fk=cliente)
            #queryset3 = Dependencia.objects.get(id_cliente1=cliente)
            #queryset4 = Dependencia.objects.get(id_cliente2=cliente)
        else:
            queryset = Cliente.objects.all()
            queryset2 = Exame.objects.all()

        print('ClienteListView')
        print(queryset)
        print(queryset2)
        return queryset, queryset2
```

Comment: Why do you return __two__ querysets from the `get_queryset` method??

Comment: i need to pass 2 or more queryset to .html ... now i'm using get_context_data to take these two querysets, but the first one (Cliente.objects) doesn't work